Size of Relay Chain state proof becomes big after enabling async backing
our team has tested our own Relay Chain(forked from polkadot-release-1.10) with async backing feature based on the wiki. Our Relay Chain has two operating parachains. However, it seems like Relay Chain's pvc size of parachain data is growing so fast and found out it was due to relay_storage_proof, which is relay_dispatch_queue_remaining_capacity(roughly 1.6mb). We don't know where to fix this problem. Thank you

Yeah, can you please create an issue in polkadot-sdk. Please include as much information as possible. Do you mean that calling relay_dispatch_queue_remaining_capacity is increasing the proof size that much?

Oh finally we figured it out. It was due to state_version=0 in Runtime which should be 1. By the way, what is this state_version used for?

There was an optimization to the structure of the trie. Large values are not part of a node or leaf anymore. Thus, it also explains why it solves your issue here :) When setting state_version = 1 this new format is used. Good that you solved it! The production networks Polkadot/Kusama using this also now :)

Thank you for your reply! And Async Backing feature is amazing!

Correct me if I'm wrong.
I think it might be caused by this:
/// We allow for 2 seconds of compute with a 6 second average block.
pub const MAXIMUM_BLOCK_WEIGHT: Weight = Weight::from_parts(
    WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND.saturating_mul(2),
    cumulus_primitives_core::relay_chain::MAX_POV_SIZE as u64,
);

For our parachain, this increases our block space fourfold.

Thank you for your reply. I think it is not related to size of parachain's blockspace. The problem is size of the relay chain state proof size while constructing parachain inherent data. We still haven't found out..
